# Angular.JS, display JSON array as table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to display the contents of arrays in a JSON file as tables, using JADE and Angular.JS.

The server passes this table structure:

```
         {
            "Table1": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Foo"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Bar"
                }
            ],
            "Table2": []
        }
```

Like this:

```
body(ng-app='myApp', ng-controller='myCtrl' ng-init='list= #{JSON.stringify(list)}')

div(ng-repeat="table in list[0]")

        .col-lg-3
            table.table.table-bordered
                thead
                    tr
                        th Title
                tbody(ng-repeat="item in table | orderBy:'id' track by item.id")
                    tr
                        td.name {{item.name}}
```

It works: two tables are displayed, each containing the values of one of the tables.

However, I would like to put "Table1" and "Table2" as titles of the two tables, and I am stuck.

My controller looks like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.nameList = []; 
    angular.element(document).ready(function(){

        for(i in $scope.list[0])
            $scope.nameList.push(i);

        console.log($scope.nameList);
    });

});
```

I need to wrap my function in the angular.element statement, otherwise $scope.list is undefined. I tried to wrap the instructions in a window.onload statement (which oddly works in another page), like this:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
    window.onload = function() {
        ...
```

But I obtained the same results.

console.log prints the correct values; however, if I try to display a value like this:

```
p {{nameList[0]}}
```

Nothing happens. I tried to pass $scope as argument to the function, but I get a '$scope is undefined' error.

My questions are:

1. How can I pass variables created inside angular.element to the main function and
2. Which method could I apply, and is considered good practice, to use the values of the array as titles of the tables?

Thanks.

Comment: all sorts of variable name mismatches and you don't need anything regarding `angular.element` in the controller to create the scope. Suggest looking through some tutorials

Comment: I don't; however, if I don't, the script cannot make use of 'list' at all; can you point out the mismatches? Can't see any.

Comment: Create a demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) . Things don't add up right with the code shown